# Array to matrix representation in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

As per my code, I ask user to enter a string. I want to convert it in 2 dimensional array of NXN size. Although N can be variable but for now considering it to be 3. I want to format the string inputted by the user as below.

For input string :

```
⌐Φ┼╨¡¬╨┴╨
```

I want to arrange like this way.

```
[⌐ Φ ┼
 ╨ ¡ ¬
 ╨ ┴ ╨]
```

Below is the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         Map<Character,Character> inputMap = new HashMap<Character,Character>();
        inputMap.put('a', '|');
        inputMap.put('b', 'β');
        inputMap.put('c', '⌐');
        inputMap.put('d', '≡');
        inputMap.put('e', '╨');
        inputMap.put('f', 'Ω');
        inputMap.put('g', '╟');
        inputMap.put('h', '¬');
        inputMap.put('i', '↔');
        inputMap.put('j', 'Σ');
        inputMap.put('k', '¥');
        inputMap.put('l', '╒');
        inputMap.put('m', '┼');
        inputMap.put('n', '«');
        inputMap.put('o', 'Φ');
        inputMap.put('p', '╔');
        inputMap.put('q', 'Є');
        inputMap.put('r', '┴');
        inputMap.put('s', 'δ');
        inputMap.put('t', '╬');         
        inputMap.put('u', '┤');
        inputMap.put('v', 'θ');
        inputMap.put('w', '●');
        inputMap.put('x', '◙');
        inputMap.put('y', 'σ');
        inputMap.put('z', '∞');

        inputMap.put(' ', '¡');

Scanner ins = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String");
        String myData = ins.nextLine();

        char arr[]=new char[myData.length()];
    arr=myData.toCharArray();

     for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

       arr[i]=inputMap.get(arr[i]);

      System.out.println( arr[i]);
    }

    }
```

how can I do this?

Comment: print a new line after every "n" elements maybe? You wouldn't get a square matrix form every time tho...

Comment: i want square matrix. but i cannot arrange array to matrix

Comment: Dude you just want to display in matrix form right? if that's the case you dont need to change array to matrix just print a new line after "n" elements, it'd display like a matrix form. You'll need to perform calculations in order to produce a square matrix every time. If you want matrix like array then you need to use jagged arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method in `String.java` `toCharArray()`. This will give you single dimensional array. Now iterate it using simple for loop. In each iteration you can print the character and at each Nth iteration print a new line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ins = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a String");
    String myData = ins.nextLine();
    ins.close();
    char []  oneDArray = myData.toCharArray();
    int N = 3; // or you can set it by asking the user
    char[][] twoDArray = new char[N][N];
    int size = oneDArray.length;
    boolean isEndReached = false;
    for(int row = 0; row < N ; row++ ){
        for(int col = 0; col < N; col++){
            int index = row*N + col;
            if(index >= size){
                isEndReached = true;
                break;
            }
            twoDArray[row][col] = oneDArray[index];
        }
        if(isEndReached){
            break;
        }
    }
    //printing...
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int row = 0; row < N ; row++ ){
        for(int col = 0; col < N; col++){
            System.out.print(twoDArray[row][col]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print("]");
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: But i cannot want single dimention array. iwant nxn array. how can do this please help with code

Comment: @TK I edited my answer and added the code

Comment: @TK thanks for accepting the answer as correct, But 1 thing I observe in your question. Do you need the map, I mean you are not using it.....In my answer I have not used it, see your requirement specifications and use the map if required.

Comment: thanks it helps me lot. if  nxn matrix not satisfied then suppose last one or two value is blank then how it replace with any symbol.Please give me an idea

Comment: for(int row = 0; row < N ; row++ ){
         for(int col = 0; col < N; col++){
          int index = row*N + col;
          if(index >= size){
           twoDArray[row][col] = '!';
          }else{
           twoDArray[row][col] = oneDArray[index];
          }
         }
        }

Comment: change the for loop in my answer as I posted above, '!' is your symbol with which you can replace your blank. You can use any symbol you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can print blank line at certain interval, e.g.:

```
String[] array = new String[10];//your map
int n = 5;
int count = 0;
for(String element : array){
    count++;
    System.out.print(element + " ");
    if(count%n == 0){
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: do not understand. i want to rearrange continuous array into nxn matrix form

Comment: how can i add arr[i] in my program. please help.. i amnew in java